# Multiple dependent variables with categorical predictors: estimation problem

Tags: anova, multiple-regression

I have two continuous variables which are my dependent variables (well they are discrete actually) and two predictors which are categorical (they are experimental treatments). `O + M ~ P + Q`
I have already broken the model into pieces and I have tested through two-way factorial ANOVAs the effect of the predictors P + Q on each of the dependent variables, O and M, separately: `O ~ P + Q + P*Q` and `M ~ P + Q + P*Q`

The dependent variables are two attitudinal items on different issues (they are both agreement to a certain statement, statement O and statement M, which are very different with each other). P, the first predictor, is a classification of belief system derived from a self-reported measure (namely the person self-set him/herself as conservative or liberal) it is a bit endogenous with O and P but not always the case (here I treat it as it is not). The variable Q is the most important one because it's the experimental treatment (split-sample); it gives us information on how the data where collected (context). 
By deciding to interact P and Q I presuppose that in specific type of Q each level of P will be affected differently in terms of the outcome variables (O and M). This was the case for attitude O, but not for the attitude M. Now I would like the combine the two samples which were divided by Q (the split-sample experimental treatment) and see whether P and Q interact when on both variables at the same time. And if yes, at how my response variables are affected.

I want to examine the effect on both response variables O + M which I already know that they are negatively correlated when predicted by P, namely, the measurements in O are likely to be the opposite than in M in all levels of P (I mean the means). As I said before I have alredy tested it in two-way factorial ANOVAs and it was significant. Moreover, something rare occurs (I have an explanation from my field) the Q predictor/experimental-treament is significant for the M dependent variable but not the interaction term P*Q

Due to the needs of my project I need to run the model mentioned above `O + M ~ P + Q` but also with the interaction term `O + M ~ P + Q + P*Q`. 
My first question is what method should I use?
I have already ran this in R, but it truncates my predictor in the `summary.lm()` output, namely, it gives me estimates only for 2 from the 7 categories of P...

From what I've read I need to apply a MANCOVA, however, is it still called a MANCOVA if there are two categorical predictors and their interaction term included?

Also, what is the type of analysis (term) for getting estimates on my dependent variables (O + M) for each level of P and Q and their interaction term? What is this type of analysis? Can you suggest any R package?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It would help me to follow your description of your situation if you would actually describe what you are doing & what the letters stand for. I have no idea what it means that Q is "distorting" something; are you talking about Q *moderating* an effect? Incidentally, if you have no covariates, you will need MANOVA, not MANCOVA.

Comment: @ gung, you are right, I gave some information from the context that this issue is set. Q is just the name of the variable, any similarity with an actual term is due to coincidence. What do you meand "if I have no covariates"? I have two covariates P and Q and their interaction. Did I understand your question?

Comment: I still can't follow this, eg you seem to have 2 different "P"s. Can you just use intelligible names (eg, *ideology* for the conservative - liberal variable)? Can you also describe your experiment? Re "covariates", sorry terminology is slippery (to my unending annoyance), what I meant is, you don't seem to be adjusting for some continuous variables that aren't of primary interest; your IVs are all *factors*. Thus, you need MANOVA (multivariate ANOVA), not MANCOVA (multivariate ANCOVA).

Comment: I am sorry I corrected it, O and M are the response and P and Q are the predictors. I thought I would make this more complicated by giving more info, I have a problem explaining what I am doing for my research, it would be better to decontextualise the variables. Thank you, you are right! it is a MANOVA... Do you know if there is a way to compare two similar models of MANOVA? One with the interaction term and one without?